# Performance difference between find and find2perl?

Tags: linux, performance, command-line, ssh, command

Is there a performance difference between find and find2perl? I work for a hosting company and I was told that our admins prefer us to use find2perl over find. Supposedly this is because find is heavier on resource usage than find2perl? Does anyone know if this is true and if so, could you please explain why?

Comment: I apologize. I think I posted this in the wrong section. Is it possible for this to be moved to Unix / Linux or should I recreate it there?

Answer (score 1):

find2perl translates the find into a perl script supposedly for later use (in perl). The man page states that is "typically faster than running find itself" and I guess that is why your sysadmins tell you to use it, or maybe they are simply perl fans.